# jQuery Mobile trigger filterablebeforefilter

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am hoping I am missing something simple here. I have created a basic jQuery MobileAutocomplete such as this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview-autocomplete-remote/ (with slight modifications using my own data source)

As suggested by the example, I have the function

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "filterablebeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
   //returns as a jquery listview using an ajax call
});
```

However I also have a select box (flipbox) which changes the url of the ajax call, I was wondering if there is a way to "refire" the call after the select box has changed with the same search terms. I've gotten so far as

```
$("#flip-select").change(function() {
    $("#autocomplete").trigger("filterablebeforefilter","something");
});
```

Obviously "something" isn't the data filterbeforefilter is expecting. That runs the function, but I'm not sure where to go next (or if I've even down the right path). Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this demo I put together:

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/TQcB8/)**

When the flipswitch is checked, I get the filterable's search input, set its value to some text and then trigger the change event on the input.  This makes the filter go and call the filterablebeforefilter handler.

```
$("#flip-checkbox").on("change", function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        var inp = $( "#autocomplete" ).filterable( "option", "input" );
        $(inp).val("boston").trigger("change");
    }
});
```

For this to work I am adding my own search input:

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search" />
</form>
```

And then I reference it in the UL:

```
<ul id="autocomplete" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Find a city..." data-filter-theme="a" data-input="#filterBasic-input"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this put on the path of where I needed to go. In my case, I did not want to change the input of the field, but using your method and the data-lastval attribute I got it working. My only hangup, is when I immediately refilled with the same variable it did not work, perhaps some sort of delay issue. So I added: `var refill = $("#filterBasic-input").attr("data-lastval");` and then triggered the change twice in a row. Once with an empty value, and then once with the refill value - works fine.