# Custom Filter Callback with added Slider innput

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to extend the functionality of the default list-view data-filter in JQuery Mobile.  I have the set up the HTML

```
<ul data-role = "listview" data-inset = "true" data-filter = "true" id = "eventList" data-filter-placeholder = "Quick Search">

</ul>
```

and provided a callback function

```
$("#eventList").filterable('option', 'filterCallback', ExtraSearch);
```

Now I would like to extend the filter to include values from a slider.

```
<input type="text" class = "filterSlider" data-type="range" name="peopleSlider" id="peopleSlider" data-highlight="true" value="5" min="1" max="10" />
```

Because the function prototype for the callback is

```
function ExtraSearch(index, searchValue)
```

I'm not sure how to call this function.

I have

```
$(".filterSlider").on("slidestop", function( event, ui ) 
{
    //alert($("#peopleSlider").val());
    ExtraSearch();
});
```

But I am not passing in the two variables to the funtion.  What I am doing at the moment is

```
if(searchValue == "")
{
    searchValue = $("#eventList").prev("form").find("input").val();
}
```

But that doesn't seem like a nice solution.  Is there a better way to do this?  I have a load more slider values to take into account and know there is probably a better way of doing this.

Thanks

OB

Comment: Here is a workaround I have used to trigger the filter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981158/jquery-mobile-trigger-filterablebeforefilter/22990996#22990996

Comment: Thanks @ezanker.  I have to say I'm struggling to understand your workaround a little but is  there not just a way to trigger the filtercallback when the checkbox changes?
`$("#filterBasic-input").trigger('change')`

Comment: There is no method on the filterable widget, so I forced a change on the filter input of the widget. If you create a jsFiddle or codepen with your setup, I can take a look...

Comment: @ezanker.  Thanks for the help, I think I got it figured out using the workaround and I get the current Value of the filter box and then use that to trigger a change
`$(inp).val(currentVal).trigger("change");`

Comment: @eznaker had it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981158/jquery-mobile-trigger-filterablebeforefilter/22990996#22990996